clone array of jquery/html elements
I have to clone some table rows. I only can select this rows based on their indexes. I can't use any common class or attribute to select the rows in one shot.
I do this like this:
const rows: JQuery<HTMLElement>[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= rowIndexes!.length - 1; i++) {
  const row = $(
    `tr[ng-reflect-data-row-index='${rowIndexes![i]}'`
  );
  rows.push(row);
}

And after this I want to clone the rows array like this:
$(rows).clone()

But with this I get the error TypeError: e.cloneNode is not a function.
So, the question is, how can I clone this array as a jquery element? After clone I want to do some other operations on it, f.e. animate, wrapAll.
Thanks.

"I can't use any common class or attribute to select the rows in one shot." of course you can do it in one shot: selectors = rowIndexes.map(index =>`tr[ng-reflect-data-row-index='${index}'`) to generate all the individual selectors, then $(selectors.join(",")) to find them all in one go.

On another note, i <= rowIndexes!.length - 1 is a strange way to express the more idiomatic i < rowIndexes!.length.

Thanks. I didn't know this possibility. I'm very new to jquery and have to use in an angular project just for one specific thing. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Another option is to build a jquery collection rather than an array, eg:  let rows = null; for (let i = 0; i <= rowIndexes!.length - 1; i++) { const row = ... ;  rows = (rows || $(row) ).add(row); }  then rows will be a jquery collection and you can do rows.clone();

You're missing a closing square bracket in tr[ng-reflect-data-row-index='${rowIndexes![i]}' It should be tr[ng-reflect-data-row-index='${rowIndexes![i]}']

Is that a copying error or in the real code?
